# Isn't the code/text ratio filter applied to question edits?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

I just came over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981523/ive-been-working-on-this-avltree-for-hours-and-i-just-understand-whats-wrong-w) and wondered, because IIRC there should be a code/text ratio filter, that should prevent from such question being allowed to be posted at all.

Am I wrong about this assumption?

I'm afraid the reason could be that the [1st attempt of posting code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24981523/1) just rendered wrongly to provide the right ratio, and just to edit it was a bad deciscion :-/ ...

If I'm not wrong with my assumptions about existence of such filter, how could the [2nd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24981523/2) of this question pass it??

Comment: I guess the problem is that first revision, afterall it wouldn't be easy for a fast automated process to determine the difference between text and wrongly formatted code.

Comment: @PeterJ Yeah, I've seen that one of course (linked) it. The questionable part is, that the edit passed IMHO.

Comment: That would be easily bypassed if the user forgot to use code formatting in the first place.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, I understood this behavior. What I didn't understand, is that the 2nd revision edit passed, that changed the body to a pure code dump question?

Comment: It seems very hard to get that sort of automatic filter right. While you're showing an obvious case, there could be valid questions with 15+ lines of code and a couple of sentences of text (especially if there are attempts details in comments), alternatively you could have askers that write extra sentences just to get it to post the question. Dealing with exceptions would probably make it more complicated for everyone involved.

Comment: @Bruno See my edits, I'm bothering about the edit has passed. The primary problem is clear for me.

Comment: Wrong link it seems

Comment: @Bruno Oopsie, yes ;)! THX for pointing out, I fixed it. I'm working on such stuff in parallel :P ...

Comment: Revisions don’t (shouldn’t? I think they did once; this might have been fixed) count because they just stop people from improving the question. Even when it’s not possible to add a real question, there’s no sense in leaving the bad formatting around.

Comment: @minitech Of course it was closed, my question still is: 1. Does such automatic filter exist? and 2. Why it doesn't apply for edits? There's not just being plain bad formatting, but a code only question after fixing the formatting problems.

Comment: Yes, but an automatic filter applied to edits would stop someone from making that fix, and there’s no point in doing that.

Comment: @minitech But if it triggers a low quality filter, either the question was crap and editing it is the wrong action, or the question only now is crap so the edit is bad.

Comment: @bjb568: Just because a question is bad doesn’t mean editing it is wrong. The question is unanswerable without a problem statement. What do we hope the asker will do? Add a problem statement. What can we hope to do in the meantime? Teach them how to format properly and close the question.

Comment: @minitech By "bad", I mean VLQ. By VLQ, I mean nuke it. If something is VLQ, by definition, all possible edits to it are too minor.

Comment: @minitech Teaching how to format? If OP can't read the formatting help on the ask page *right next to the textarea* and doesn't bother to do anything about the post preview *right next to the textarea* looking like crap, OP can't be bothered to contribute to the community and should be question banned.

Comment: @bjb568 ok​​​​​

Comment: @bjb568 _'Teaching how to format?'_ But isn't teaching how to format code correctly useless, without teaching how to ask _"correctly"_ with the minimum of an accepted question form. Such the editor also would be urged to add some explanatory text (even if it's just the repeated question title + here's my code or such) IMHO?

Comment: @minitech Please note my point from my previous comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: bjb is expressing incredulity at my suggestion that we teach people how to format.

Comment: @minitech Ah, got it now. I was just wondering, because I came over similar _"low quality blockers"_ when editing questions.

Comment: @minitech It doesn't hurt telling people how to use `s and indentation for lists, my point is that telling them to indent their code when there are so many more other problems won't help.